# phpdocumentor @example number of line

Tags: phpdoc, phpdocumentor2

I'm wondering how to use this.
I'm trying to use this:
https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/example.html

I'm using it like this:

```
/**
  * Format date/timestamp to localized format
  *
  * @example site/modules/KeyAgencyGeneral/Helper/Page.php 247 16 my description
  */
```

The starting line does work, but the number of lines doesn't, it's displayed as part of the description.

In the documentation it says to use it like this:

```
@example [location] [<start-line> [<number-of-lines>] ] [<description>]
```

When I try brackets it doesn't work at all, so I don't know how to limit the amount of lines displayed.

(side question: is it possible to enable highlighting in the example, or display line numbers?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In:

```
>php bin\phpDocumentor.phar -V
phpDocumentor version v2.8.5
```

It works very good:)

For example:

```
/**
 * configure the system
 * @example BillingCommand.php  98 3 some Date methods
 */
protected function configure()
{
...........
```

you have got a three lines from 98:

[image]

*(phpDocumentor finds example in source file’s folder)*

To enable highlighting in the example, or display line numbers you must edit the templates used to render documentation. Copy and modify one....